# Call to a member function getMethod() on a non-object in /var/www/html/app/code/local/Openpay/Banks/Model/Observer.php on line 16

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, php-5.4

I have implemented a third party api and I am getting bellow error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getMethod() on a non-object in
>   /var/www/html/app/code/local/Openpay/Banks/Model/Observer.php on line
>   14

at line 14 I have below code:

```
if(Mage::getConfig()->getModuleConfig('Openpay_Banks')->is('active', 'true')){
    $order_ids_list = $order_ids->getOrderIds();
    $order_id  = $order_ids_list[0];
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);

    $code = Mage::getModel('Openpay_Banks_Model_Method_Banks')->getCode();

    if($order->getPayment()->getMethod() == $code){
        $args = array(
            'order' => $order->getIncrementId(),
            'id' => $order->getPayment()->getOpenpayPaymentId(),
        );

        $this->_redirect('print', 'payments', $code, $args);
    }
```

what I can do to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

I found that when I used below code

```
$order_id = array_pop( $order_ids_list);
```

it return null value, I don't know why, so in order to fix that I store the value of array in another keys variable and then access keys variable to pass the orderId value in order variable.

```
$keys = array_keys($order_ids_list);
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($keys[0]);
```